Need Help Parameterizing a Jenkinsfile
I have a Jenkinsfile template that our organization has adopted where project teams just have to set key-value pairs and our framework will handle the rest. I've included a sample of the top of the Template. We have multiple of these templates (for different use cases) which all need to import the exact same variables. I would like to somehow create a function to accomplish this processing using a Shared Library.
import java.util.HashMap 
import java.util.Iterator 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat 
import java.util.Date

def call(config, body) { //  ======================================================================================================= //  =======================================   JenkinsFile Processing ====================================== //  =======================================================================================================


// evaluate the config block, and collect configuration into the object
def pipelineParams = [:]
body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
body.delegate = pipelineParams
body()
println("Template Name: CICD_JAVA_TEMPLATE")
PipelineEnvironment = "${env.JENKINS_INSTANCE}"
echo "Pipeline Environment: ${PipelineEnvironment}"

gitRepoBranch = "${body.GIT_REPO_BRANCH}"
Credential = "${body.CREDENTIAL_ID}"
ProgramName = "${body.PROGRAM_NAME}"
ProjectName = "${body.PROJECT_NAME}"
project_root = "${body.PROJECT_ROOT}"
junit_root = "${body.JUNIT_ROOT}"
sonarModules = "${body.SONAR_MODULES}"
groupID = "${body.GROUP_ID}"
artifactID = "${body.ARTIFACT_ID}"
scmType = "${body.SCM_TYPE}"
codeCoverageType = "${body.CODE_COVERAGE_TYPE}"
codeQualityType = "${body.QUALITY_SCAN_TYPE}"
securityScanType = "${body.SECURITY_SCAN_TYPE}"
deployType = "${body.DEPLOY_TYPE}"

etc. 

if ("${env.JOB_NAME}".endsWith("CI")) CITemplatePipeline() 
if ("${env.JOB_NAME}".endsWith("CD")) CDTemplatePipeline()

return this 
}

For better understanding, here's how a portion of the CITemplatePipeline function looks and uses variables that are defined:
def CITemplatePipeline() {
    node(buildNode) {
        performPreStage()
        withEnv([
            "JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}",   
            "ASA_HOME=${ASA_HOME}",
            "CC_HOME=${CC_HOME}"
        ]) {
            timeout(time: timeoutA, unit: 'MINUTES'){functionTimer({
                performStageA(isContainerNode, stageAContainerLabel, A, PullFromSCM, BUILD_TAG, scmType,
                    gitRepoBranch, gitRepoURL, Credential, RTCLiveURL, RTCTrainURL, BuildDefinition, ProjectName)
                }, "StageA")},
timeout(time: timeoutA, unit: 'MINUTES'){functionTimer({
                performStageB(isContainerNode, stageBContainerLabel, B, etc.)
                }, "StageB")},
...........
Stage J

I've tried creating another function that would handle all the processing as seen below:
def call(config, body) { 

performJenkinsfileProcessing(config, body)

if ("${env.JOB_NAME}".endsWith("CI")) CITemplatePipeline() 
if ("${env.JOB_NAME}".endsWith("CD")) CDTemplatePipeline()

return this

However, I get an issue a DSL error as variables that are created from the key-value pairs are not available later on in the template.
Some ideas that I'm considering are:

Creating an object that would be able to handle all of these key-value pairs that could be returned from the performJenkinsfileProcessing. Said object could then be passed to other functions wholesale or pieces.

Somehow setting the variable within performJenkinsfileProcessing() as global so they would be able to be used

Rework the functions performStageX to somehow be able to access values


I understand this is a weird problem, but happy to provide more details in order to give a better wholistic picture of the why.
